# How to calculate distance with Azure Maps API

Tags: javascript, azure-maps

I need to calculate distance  between a set of origins and destinations like Bing Map Distance Matrix API, but in my case with Azure Map API. It's possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Azure Maps platforms has a distance matrix service called Route Matrix: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/route/postroutematrixpreview

Comment: This is a new functionality, a few months ago did not exist, I personally requested this functionality similar to the one that Mapquest has. Thank you for reply.

Comment: Yes. I added it as an answer for others who come across this question.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to manually pair each origin with each destination. You can use Azure Maps [routing API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/routeservice/getroutedirections) to get the distance between an origin and a destination.

Comment: @hnakao11 you link is a goner just placing a current one here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/route